# Where can I find tsx files in apk

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I want to fetch source code from `.apk` file but I can't.
Can anyone briefly explain how react native works and where is `js` sources located?

For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "MainComponent";
    }
}
```

Where can I find the "MainComponent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS sources stored in `assets/index.android.bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

An Android `apk` is basically a zipped directory, which contains of some raw resources (images, layout files, ..) and a `classes.dex` (*Dalvik Executable*) file. This file contains all actual code and interests us the most.
First rename the APK file to ***appName.zip*** and extract by any application. Look inside the folders, May you find what you're looking for, if not you have to decompile the `classes.dex`. There are several tools like [**this**](http://www.droidviews.com/decompile-recompile-apk-easy-tool/) and [**this**](https://www.technologywindow.com/edit-android-applications-using-apktool/) one, you can use to work with the `.dex` file.

Just remember it's possible that the app was obfuscated by the developer, in this case it will make the understanding of the decompiled code much more difficult.